# Should I use a dark background on a home page

Tags: homepage

I am creating a music website and I want it to be elegant and seductive. I have placed a background image of a woman dancing. I have edited it in such a way that the background is dark and the woman is a gradient of the website's colours. The logo and name are white. Should I go ahead with this design or is there a negative aspect to having a dark background in the homepage no matter how sexy you want the site to be?

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of the design? This seems more a graphics question than UX, unless there are visibility issues (i.e. can't see links or how to navigate the website).

Answer (score 1):

There is no UX "rule" or "position" as relates to background color EXCEPT in how it works with your users.  There is debate and questions as to how background color and contrast affects legibility and comfort as it relates to reading a lot of text.

This seems more a design issue than UX. Regardless, the UX way of answering this question is to do user testing. Present your design (and alternatives) to your target audience and observe their reaction.

Comment: thanks for that. One more thing and this is a small issue so i didn't want to post another question. I cant seem to decide between a big search bar, like designspiration or myspace , or a normal one, like here in stack overflow. The search bar is for searching albums and artists. should i keep the big one in the homepage or should i replace it with a catchy subtitle?

Comment: That's a great question -- and I'll give you the standard answer: ask your users. What do they like? What are they comfortable with? What makes sense to them? If you haven't much money ask friends and others who are the target audience. As your site grows you can do some A/B testing and get an answer based on the observed preferences of your users.

Comment: A search bar can be sized proportionate to its importance to the site. Wikipedia, Google, etc, it's rather large and commands a lot of attention. On a site like http://alistapart.com/ search is a secondary function but they've cleverly had the bar grow as a user hovers into it.